# Allowing many (unverified) apps to run in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal

I downloaded a package that contains a bunch of executables. When I try to run any of them from the terminal, I get the "cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified" thing, so I cannot run it. I know I can go in the Security settings to allow this one app to run. But this requires doing it one by one. Is there something I can do from the terminal to allow all apps in a directory (say) to run?

Comment: Why the close vote? This is a question about how to automate this, which involves some (perhaps trivial) level of scripting. I'd think that's on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer. To allow unverified “program” to run, from the terminal, you can do:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine “program”
```

Also works for multiple binaries within a directory,

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine *
```